# what is it called that angular function has multiple options of return types

Tags: angular, typescript

In the Angular docs I read this:

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree
```

So does it mean that this function can return one of the types?
And is this an Angular thing or a TypeScript thing?
I tried searching for multiple return types on a function but I couldn't find anything about this construct, neither on the calling side, whether I should cast the result to one of the types, and how i could do that.

Or does my implementation need to implement only one of the 5 options?

Comment: It's a Typescript feature. It's called [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types). Yes, it means the return could be of any of the types.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: I think I sort of understand. Should I be able to do this? `let result: Observable<boolean>  = guard.canActivate(null, null);` (compiler says no: "Type 'boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.") My function returns an observable in this case, can I cast it somehow?

Comment: you should be fine to replace it with `let result = guard.canActivate(null, null);`. The type of result will just be implicit. Either that or you will need to use the entire union type signature when specifying the type for `result`.